# How minimize this boolean equation?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to minimize boolean equation, but I have no idea how to do.
Here is the equation

Y = ABC~D + A~(BCD) + ~(A+B+C+D).

Can it be minimized?

Comment: The usual way is to write a truth-table. For $4$ input variables, it has $2^4 = 16$ rows called minterms. In a second step, fill the $16$ truth values in a `Karnaugh Veitch` map to find an expression with a minimal number of implicants.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're using $\sim$ as the Boolean complement with prefix notation.
So with a more standard notation your expression is
$$Y=ABCD'+A(BCD)'+(A+B+C+D)'.$$
This expression can be simplified in different ways, and it is not clear to me which one you'd like.
Here goes its DNF form:
\begin{align}
Y 
&= ABCD'+A(B'+C'+D')+A'B'C'D'       \tag{de Morgan laws}\\
&= A(BCD'+B'+C'+D')+A'B'C'D'        \tag{distributuvity}\\
&= AB'+AC'+AD'+A'B'C'D'             \tag{absorption & distrib}
\end{align}
where absorption comes from $BCD'+D'=D'$.
Now 
\begin{align}
AB' + A'B'C'D'
&= B'(A+A'C'D')                        \tag{distributivity}\\
&= B'((A+A')(A+C')(A+D'))              \tag{distributivity}\\
&= B'(A+C')(A+D')                      \tag{since $A+A'=1$}\\
&= B'(A+C'D')                          \tag{distributivity}\\
&= AB' + B'C'D',                       \tag{distributivity}
\end{align}
whence
$$Y=AB'+AC'+AD'+B'C'D'.$$

From here it also follows that
$$Y=A(BCD)'+(B+C+D)',$$
which is obtained from the original one by erasing the first summand and also the first summand of the complement of the last one.
I suspect this is really what you want.